# How to do recovery reactive form statement in Angular?

Tags: angular

I use reactive forms in Angular, and I store all selected values in session storage to restore after time and activate form with exist values.

Problem is that some values of forms, or better to say elements of form have dependencies.

For example, if user select dropdown element it must send request to server to retrieve data and fill the next element form. Such sequences can be more. When one field depended from another.

When I read stored values from storage I have trouble in activating element of form and them sequence calling.

How do you handle that in Angular conceptually?

Comment: I would guess that they voted down because it is challenging to understand what you are attempting to do without some concrete code. Could you provide a code example of what you are describing? Or even better, a stackblitz?

Comment: @DeborahK it would be easier to understand what you are asking if there was a code example. The wording is difficult to understand, could you further elaborate on your issue?

Comment: @BinaryBuilder I assume you didn't mean to address that question to me but rather to the OP?

Comment: @DeborahK yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are having trouble showing the elements dynamically based on chosen values selected.

In Angular, you can use the `*ngIf` for DOM elements to trigger showing them. When you send an HTTP request to a server to retrieve data, that is considered an async function. This will return an Observable of the data type in Angular which you can then subscribe. Therefore, when the data eventually is received, if the `*ngIf` is based on the data received, it can trigger the DOM element to be added to the page.

For example:
*Assuming there is a service layer on the client side called **DataService***

**Component:**

```
data;

constructor(dataService: DataService) {
}

this.dataService().getData().subscribe(value => this.data = value);
```

**HTML:**

```
...

<div *ngIf="data">
  * Other Form Elements *
</div>

...
```

Further information can be found here:
Forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview
HTTP: https://angular.io/guide/http